# php convert string hex without encode

Tags: php, string, utf-8, encode

I receive data like this:

```
$string = "\x01\x03\r\x08\xc0";
```

From this variable how to output (with `echo`) the same value?

For example on python, when I type:

```
$ print [string]
```

I get this

```
["\x01\x03\r\x08\xc0"]
```

Note:
Without do `$string = '\x01\x03\r\x08\xc0'` because I uses a server who receives data and the string variable is the data.

Can someone can help me?

Comment: If it's very important then you should do all you can to make the question as clear as possible. This is quite the opposite in my opinion.

Comment: Try using `addslashes()` function over your parameter, then output your string.

Answer (score 0):

when php interpreter reach the line:

```
$string = "\x01\x03\r\x08\xc0";
```

it automatically parse string between double quotes. so you can not get real string. but if you can guarantee that response you get is a valid hex, use function bin2hex(). in that case you can convert result of that function to what you want. something like:

```
$str = bin2hex($hex);
$real_str = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i+=2){
    $real_str .= '\\x'.$str[$i].$str[$i+1];
 }
 echo $real_str;
```

Comment: Could we uses urlencode($string) and replace '%' by '\n' ?

Comment: urlencode function may act strang, i dont know. by the way there are lots of solution. you may test them one by one.